# extjs checkbox data rendering issue

Tags: extjs, checkbox

php return data from server side but not extjs not render the value of fields

i'm using xtype: 'checkbox'

{"total":1,"success":true,"locks":[{"id":"1","record_id":"11","is_unreachable":"1","is_directory_Lock":"1","is_Internet_Lock":"0","is_partner_Lock":"1","is_home_business":"1","is_top_listing":"1","is_mole":"1","is_pre_call":"1","is_new_business":"1","is_free_adv":"1","is_verified":"1","is_reviewed":"1","is_idr":"1"}]}

json array return from server

Answer (score 0):

you have to paste you code.

But why not go to the example:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/grid/array-grid.html

Answer (score 0):

Ext.define('UserApp.view.uiTypes.LockFeature',{
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    collapsible: true,
    flex: 1,
    height: 200,
    width: 600,
    store: null,
    itemId: 'lockfeature',
    layout:{
        type: 'table',
        columns: 3
    },

```
items:[{

        xtype: 'checkbox',
        boxLabel: 'Is Unreachable',
        name: 'is_unreachable',
        id: 'is_unreachable',
        dataIndex: 'is_unreachable',
        inputValue: 'true', 
        uncheckedValue: 'false',
        value: true, 


},{

    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'is_unreachable_update',
    fieldLabel: 'Last Update',

},{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'update_by_user',
    fieldLabel: 'By'
}],


initComponent: function(){
    console.log(this.table);
    console.log(this.record_id);
    var table = this.table;
    var parentTable = table.split('_');
    console.log(parentTable[0]);
    var store = Ext.create('UserApp.store.LockFeature');
    store.getProxy().setExtraParam('table',parentTable[1]);
    store.getProxy().setExtraParam('tab',parentTable[1]);
    store.getProxy().setExtraParam('saving_table', table);
    store.getProxy().setExtraParam('record_id',this.record_id);
    this.store = store;
    this.callParent(arguments);
    store.load();

}
```

});